# Why my dropdown menu isn't appearing on hover?

Tags: css

Why the dropdown menu isn't working on css hover? I've seen people do it on youtube and it looks pretty simple.

HTML

```
<div class ="top-bar">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="logo" src="Images/logo-blanco.png" alt="logo">
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="drop">Demos</a>
                            <ul class="drop-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" class="color" id="castellano">Castellano</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="color">Ingles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="color">Videos</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Como Trabajo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quien Soy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hablan de mi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    top: 20px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}



ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65%;
    margin-right: 2px;

}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

ul li a.color {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-left: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-right: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    font-size: 130%;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(179, 176, 176, 0.5);

}

ul li ul.drop-menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}

.drop:hover .drop-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

I'm pretty new to this so hopefully I've included enough code. I guess perhaps something else is stopping it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your css is incorrect. Your `.drop-menu` class isnt in the `drop` class, it is next to it.

I think if you change your css to this:

```
.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}

.drop:hover + .drop-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

It is going to work. The `+` operator is for selecting css neighbours. But you can also just end your `a` after the whole `.drop-menu` like this.

```
<li>
 <a href="#" class="drop">Demos
   <ul class="drop-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="color" id="castellano">Castellano</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="color">Ingles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="color">Videos</a></li>
   </ul>
 </a>
</li>
```

Then your css is correct and you dont have to change that.

**EDIT:** i removed the `a` tag in your code as it is officialy only allowed to contain inline elements, Also, i removed the `top` from the `ul li ul.drop-menu`. Only use `top, left, right, bottom` on `absolute` elements.

I also changed the `hover` on the submenu in the CSS. I now used the `>` selector, which means: get the **DIRECT** child of the selected parent. Docs [here](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    top: 20px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}



ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 65%;
    margin-right: 2px;

}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

ul li a.color {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-left: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border-right: 0.5px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    font-size: 130%;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(179, 176, 176, 0.5);

}

ul li ul.drop-menu {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}

.drop-menu {
    display: none;
}

.drop:hover > .drop-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class ="top-bar">
  <div class="row">
   <img class="logo" src="Images/logo-blanco.png" alt="logo">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="drop">Demos
          <ul class="drop-menu">
              <li><a href="#" class="color" id="castellano">Castellano</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="color">Ingles</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="color">Videos</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
      <li><a href="#" >Como Trabajo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Quien Soy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hablan de mi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacta</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So now that I've had some time to work with this a little... As soon as go down to try and select the drop down menu, the dropdown menu disappears.

Comment: edited my answer, i see that it doesn't work in this small area, but if you expand it it works. You can change the width of your `li` elements accordingly.

Comment: i hope my explanation is just a little bit clear! Have a nice day

Comment: Great explanation. I only used top because I need to get the dropdown menu to appear further down the page by about 20px. Wasn't sure how else to approach that one.

Comment: use margin-top or padding-top :)